# How can I make these images stay in a "grid"?

Tags: html, css

so I have some images with text underneath them, I want them to be the same size. And that worked, but I also want them to be in a sort of "raster", not a visible. But so they are on 1 line. I don't even know if the CSS is correct. It would also be cool if once someone donates, their image and name would appear directly on the site, this is probably hard. So that the images align is good enough for me.

**CSS**

```
.col-md_staffblock{
    margin: 30px auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px auto;
    padding: 10px 10px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 >DONATORS</h1>
        <p>Donations help us keep our servers online 24/7.</p>
        <div class="row stafflist">

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/JOSH_KING222.png">
                <h2>JOSH_KING222</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/BuddySven.png">
                <h2>BuddySven</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/AllexX.png">
                <h2>AllexX</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/fond99.png">
                <h2>fond99</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/II_Sebs.png">
                <h2>II_Sebs</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/obesemessFTW69.png">
                <h2>obesemessFTW69</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/DcemilO.png">
                <h2>DcemilO</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="img/sonicboom62798.png">
                <h2>sonicboom62798</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this html is the same for every image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question my solution for it goes like that:-

`HTML` I changed your images so that I can have a preview you can use your default images if you want

```
<h1 >DONATORS</h1>
        <p>Donations help us keep our servers online 24/7.</p>
        <div class="row stafflist">

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>JOSH_KING222</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>BuddySven</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>AllexX</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>fond99</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>II_Sebs</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>obesemessFTW69</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>DcemilO</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md_staffblock">
                <img width="100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/100">
                <h2>sonicboom62798</h2>
                <p>Donator</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Normal `CSS`

```
.stafflist {
  display: flex;
}

.col-md_staffblock  {
  margin: 10px
}

h2 {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

Using `CSS3 grids` Just change the number 8 to whatever number you want and you'll get a grid in X columns

```
.stafflist {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr) ;

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Now I get this: https://imgur.com/a/5U0DhQO
It is to close to the left border, how can i spread it more?

Comment: @Matz beside the above solution if you are new to html and css coding try to read more about css grid as in css grid you can position your divs and images in whichever way you want and they can be responsive and totally controllable for how you want them to be positioned or displayed.

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it with padding. Ty

Answer (score 0):

based on Matz answer, you can use the css grid for your class .stafflist as follow
you are fixing your div to display 8 columns distributed across your page

```
.stafflist {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr ;

}
```

as i mentioned earlier in my comment try to read more about css grid, its very helpful and you will have total control on a responsive page.